# Cut the border of the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I did draw a graph, and I need to call `axes (aspect = 'equal')`, in order to keep the proportions of the coordinates.

However, inserting axes, it also inserts a border, like in [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXDJL.png) (the grey area is the border inserted by the axes()).

I tried to set xlim() and ylim(), but these commands act only on the figure , not on the border.

Please help to set the axes border to absolute 0, and in the same time to set the aspect `equal`.

EDIT:

Here is an image of the graph -- I use only this code to set the figure.

(One can see the white border around the graph) :

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.axis([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
[spine.set_visible(False) for spine in ax.spines.values()]

...NETWORKX CALLS...
```

```
xmax = max(points, key = lambda x : x[0])[0]
ymax = max(points, key = lambda x : x[1])[1]
xmin = min(points, key = lambda x : x[0])[0]
ymin = min(points, key = lambda x : x[1])[1]
xlim (xmin, xmax)
ylim (ymin, ymax)
show()
```

I wish to use at maximum the frame space, and cut completely the border used by axes.

[image]

Comment: I know that it is difficult, because, even if I am working for about 1 year with matplotlib, I never met this problem before. For a hacker who already solved it, it should be trivial ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood the question correctly, I believe this should achieve what you want:

```
ax = plt.gca()

# Make axes occupy whole canvas
ax.set_position([0,0,1,1])

# Same scale on x- and y-axes, change x- and y-limits to keep
# axes ratio and position
# 'equal' gives same scaling on x- and y-axes
# 'datalim' changes the xlim and ylim to fit the axes inside its boundary
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')

ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
[spine.set_visible(False) for spine in ax.spines.values()]
```

Comment: HEHEH ! How did I not know ?